# start a service listening to a port on tomcat server

Tags: tomcat, port

I'd like to add a service to the tomcat server which listens to a port number and establish a tcp/ip connection with the client to send and receive some data.

I tried to run a servlet with load-on-startup value = 1 and created an infinite loop in the service method. but that's not helping me.
so please give me some ideas to proceed
thanks in advance

Comment: What data you want to send/receive and what is the intention behind it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only the **init** method of the HttpServlet class will run based on the *load-on-startup* value. It's sort of like a constructor in a regular Java class. The only parameter available for you to use inside that method is *ServletConfig*. This is particularly useful for doing resources initializations (i.e. database connection).

If you do not need both *HttpServletRequest* and *HttpServletResponse* in writing your code then put your code inside this **init** method. Otherwise the best thing you can do is to point a **welcome-file** to a **servlet-mapping** based on a **url-pattern**. It will run the doGet method automatically and both *HttpServletRequest* and *HttpServletResponse* is now available for you to use. You can then do your infinite loop inside this method.

Comment: One thing to notice though that the init method runs automatically and only once after you deployed your web app in tomcat. With the doGet method you still need to manually access the website URL just once.